# C++ Boost read_json crash and I had #define BOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE

Tags: c++, json, boost, crash, thread-safety

Recently other people upgraded our boost library, now I see this coredump when a read_json function is called heavily. Never seen this before. And I have #define BOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE in the code, that's why this didn't happen before. Really need help!Thanks!

Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.

```
    #0  0x00007f062ce0d094 in std::mem_fun1_t<int, boost::spirit::classic::impl::grammar_helper_base<boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> > >, boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> >*>::operator() (this=0x7f06120f4c90, __p=0x7f05f813faa0, __x=0x7f06120f4df0) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-spcdn-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../../include/c++/4.5.2/bits/stl_function.h:605
            in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-spcdn-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../../include/c++/4.5.2/bits/stl_function.h
    #0  0x00007f062ce0d094 in std::mem_fun1_t<int, boost::spirit::classic::impl::grammar_helper_base<boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> > >, boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> >*>::operator() (this=0x7f06120f4c90, __p=0x7f05f813faa0, __x=0x7f06120f4df0) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-spcdn-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../../include/c++/4.5.2/bits/stl_function.h:605
    #1  0x00007f062ce0c66e in std::binder2nd<std::mem_fun1_t<int, boost::spirit::classic::impl::grammar_helper_base<boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> > >, boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> >*> >::operator() (this=0x7f06120f4c90, __x=@0x7f06001446e0) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-spcdn-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../../include/c++/4.5.2/backward/binders.h:154
    #2  0x00007f062ce0b87e in std::for_each<std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<boost::spirit::classic::impl::grammar_helper_base<boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> > >**, std::vector<boost::spirit::classic::impl::grammar_helper_base<boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> > >*, std::allocator<boost::spirit::classic::impl::grammar_helper_base<boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> > >*> > > >, std::binder2nd<std::mem_fun1_t<int, boost::spirit::classic::impl::grammar_helper_base<boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> > >, boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> >*> > > (__first=..., __last=..., __f=...) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-spcdn-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../../include/c++/4.5.2/bits/stl_algo.h:4185
    #3  0x00007f062ce0aa88 in boost::spirit::classic::impl::grammar_destruct<boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> > > (self=0x7f06120f4df0) at /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/classic/core/non_terminal/impl/grammar.ipp:324
    #4  0x00007f062ce09c5f in boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> >::~grammar (this=0x7f06120f4df0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/classic/core/non_terminal/grammar.hpp:52
    #5  0x00007f062ce093f7 in boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::~json_grammar (this=0x7f06120f4df0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/boost/property_tree/detail/json_parser_read.hpp:162
    #6  0x00007f062ce0987f in boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json_internal<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > > (stream=..., pt=..., filename="") at /usr/include/boost/property_tree/detail/json_parser_read.hpp:310
    #7  0x00007f062ce08eb6 in boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > > (stream=..., pt=...) at /usr/include/boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp:45
```

Answer (score 2):

Everywhere you include json_parser.hpp or Spirit, BOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE must be defined. Defining it globally would be safest, in case another part of boost/yourApp uses Spirit without your knowledge.

For any inclusion where this isn't defined, Sprit annoyingly makes a static variable in grammar.ipp that'll be shared amongst all instances of Spirit. Your grammar_destruct error is because Spirit is missing this define in one of your modules.

Comment: This BOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE was a nasty surprise, I was really lucky, where do I find this "option" documented?
Can't see it here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/property_tree.html